# systemtap probing by line number "analysis failed"

Tags: systemtap, probe

Using systemtap with file name and line number is generating an error, where as using the (mangled) function name is fine. What am I doing wrong here?

```
// fails with 
// semantic error: no match
// Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
probe process("a.out").statement("*@hello.cpp:5") {
  printf("in test\n")
}

// succeeds
probe process("a.out").function("_Z4testv").return {
  printf("in test\n")
}

//content of source of a.out 
#include <iostream>

void test() {
  int a = 1;
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}

int main()
{
  test();
}

//stap command
sudo stap  a.stp -c "./a.out"
```

linux version `3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64`

stap version `2.8/0.160`

directory content: `a.out  hello.cpp a.stp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the expected behaviour if your program lacks debuginfo but has a symbol table - i.e., if it was compiled without `CFLAGS=-g`.